# Is UnitOfWork equals Transaction? Or it is more than that?

Tags: design-patterns, data-access-layer, unit-of-work

The internet is full of information about `UnitOfWork` pattern; even SO is not an exception.

I still do not understand something about it. In my understanding `UnitOfWork = Transaction in DB`. Thats all; nothing more, nothing less.

Is this correct?

My confusion is due to how it is implemented in different `ORM`s. `NHibernate` uses `ISession` for more than just a `Transaction`. `Dapper` leaves everything to you.

My question here is about design pattern only without considering any `ORM` or technology.

If it is more than just `Transaction`, please explain how.

**Edit 1**

Reference to [this](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) link as suggested in answer by @David Osborne.

> A Unit of Work keeps track of everything you do during a business
> transaction that can affect the database. When you're done, it figures
> out everything that needs to be done to alter the database as a result
> of your work.

So this means `UnitOfWork` is `DBTransaction` **and More**.

Following are its additional responsibilities: -

- Maintain state of what you have changed, inserted, deleted in this session of work.
- Based on this state, modify the database when work is done.

Although not clearly mentioned in quote above, but it also may control batching of queries.

Is my understanding correct now?

Comment: I would say it depends on your use case and what your UnitOfWork (aka. CreateCustomer, MakeBooking, CreateInvoice,...) should do.... I use it that way with one transcation, but a Unit Of Work could also be more than one transcation. If more than one you then you have to control the rollbacks/revert of transcations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It [originates](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html), AFAIK, from the need for ORM tools to track the [persistence] state of objects during a logical/business transaction.

How a unit of work manages this, and its relationship with the underlying storage technology and the objects stored, is an implementation detail.

A database transaction with a number of SQL statements in between, is arguably also a unit of work. However, the key difference, I suppose, is that the unit of work, as defined in the pattern, has abstracted that level of detail to an object level.

Comment: It can. Again, it depends and is at the discretion of the implementation. I know that NHibernate will batch operations when the conditions are right.

Comment: @DavidOsborne I'm quite sure it even dates back to a time when ORMs weren't a thing yet :)

Comment: Interesting point, @guillaume31. My experience with it only goes back as far as Fowler's pattern.

Answer (score 23):

A `UnitOfWork` is a business transaction. Not necessarily a technical transaction (db transaction) but often tied to technical transactions.

In the [enterprise application patterns](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) it is defined as

> Maintains a list of objects affected by a business transaction and coordinates the writing out of changes and the resolution of concurrency problems.

It does not define how changes are written nor the storage type.

An applcation might write changes to a

- database using SQL
- file system using streams
- persistence service using http requests
- distributed cache or even in-memory storage using method invocations

A `UnitOfWork` (business transaction) collects changes to business objects and ensures that other business transactions will only see valid business objects.

E.g. When your application executes a use case it modifies business objects. If two business transactions (usually use cases) are executed in parallel your application must take care about the changes that each business transaction performs and the time when other business transactions will see them.

Technically this is often done using a db transaction. Thus a unit of work is usually a db transaction.

Applications that use ORM-frameworks to handle persistence usually have a one-to-one relationship between the unit of work and the db transaction. So the difference between a unit of work and a db transaction is usually not relevant for developers.