# How to connect ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application to SQL Server database? I do not know how to configure the Program.cs

Tags: entity-framework-core, database-connection, asp.net-core-6.0

I have been trying to connect my app to a SQL Server database using ASP.NET Core 6 but it always fails. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Repository code where it fails:

```
result = db.QueryFirstOrDefault<tbUsers>(SqlQuery, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
>
> InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource retry)
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
> Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryRowImpl(IDbConnection cnn, Row row, ref CommandDefinition command, Type effectiveType) in SqlMapper.cs
> Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryFirstOrDefault(IDbConnection cnn, string sql, object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable commandTimeout, Nullable commandType) in SqlMapper.cs
> nickramen.DataAccess.Repositories.UsersRepository.Ingresar(string Username, string Password) in UsersRepository.cs
>
> result = db.QueryFirstOrDefault(SqlQuery, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
> nickramen.WebUI.Controllers.AccountController.Login(UserViewModel model) in AccountController.cs
>
> var user = _usersRepository.Ingresar(model.Username, model.Password);
> lambda_method28(Closure , object , object[] )
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()

This is my code:

`Program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using nickramen.DataAccess.Entities;
using nickramen.DataAccess.Interfaces;
using nickramen.DataAccess.Repositories;

// Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("NickramenConnectionString"))
);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IRolesRepository, RolesRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUsersRepository, UsersRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IJobApplicationRepository, JobApplicationRepository>();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

This is my `NickramenDbContext`:

```
// NickramenDbContext.cs
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace nickramen.DataAccess
{
    public class NickramenDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public NickramenDbContext(DbContextOptions<NickramenDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public static string ConnectionString { get; set; } = "";

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
            }
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `AppDbContext` (generated by EF Core reverse engineering):

```
// <auto-generated> This file has been auto generated by EF Core Power Tools. </auto-generated>
#nullable disable
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace nickramen.DataAccess.Entities;

public partial class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext()
    {
    }

    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<tbJobApplication> tbJobApplication { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<tbPersons> tbPersons { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<tbRoles> tbRoles { get; set; }

    // rest of the code
}
```

This is the `appsettings.json` file:

```
// appsettings.json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "NickramenConnectionString": "Server=Insertserver;Database=Insertdb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Here's my `Repository.cs`:

```
using Dapper;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using nickramen.DataAccess.Entities;
using nickramen.DataAccess.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace nickramen.DataAccess.Repositories
{
    public class UsersRepository : IUsersRepository
    {
        public tbUsers Ingresar(string Username, string Password)
        {
            const string SqlQuery = "UDP_Acce_tbUsers_Login";
            var result = new tbUsers();
            var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
            parameters.Add("@usu_Username ", Username, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);
            parameters.Add("@usu_Password", Password, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);

            using (var db = new SqlConnection(NickramenDbContext.ConnectionString))
            {
                result = db.QueryFirstOrDefault<tbUsers>(SqlQuery, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed that you already used ef core for your app, so why not using it to query your database? Here's the [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and you might take a look at the docuements.  pls correct me if I misunderstood your requirement.

Comment: could you pls change `var db = new SqlConnection(NickramenDbContext.ConnectionString)` to `var db = new SqlConnection("{hardcode_your_connection_string_here}")` for a test? because the error message is pointing to the connectionstirng.

Comment: by the way, what you have is `builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>` but not the `builder.Services.AddDbContext<NickramenDbContext>`, is there anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

the error message `The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.` you got always means that your code didn't get the connection string. And the code throwing the exception is trying to get `NickramenDbContext.ConnectionString` which might be "". I had a test in my side and I got the result like this.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public static string ConnectionString { get; set; } = "";

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
        }
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Movie> Movie { get; set; }

}
```

[image]

So my idea is that you might try to hardcode the connection string in your problematic line for a test, to see if this exception still existed.

Comment: `ServerVersion = {"Invalid operation. The connection is closed."}`

This is what I get even tho it is hardcoded.

Comment: the error message is about the connection, and I'm afraid that you could try to fully manage the connections yourself but not let Dapper to do it automatically. You might take a look at [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41054369) to add `connection.Open();`