# registering DbContext with multiple parameters

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, inversion-of-control

I'm trying to inject TenantProvider into DbContext

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, long>
{
    public int? _tenantId;

    public ITenantProvider _tenantProvider;

    public AppDbContext(
        DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options,
        ITenantProvider tenantProvider
        )
    : base(options)
    {
        _tenantProvider = tenantProvider;
    }
```

but I don't understand how to register it correctly - if I put the breakpoint in the constructor - `tenantProvider` is `null`.

The bit from `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => AppDbContextOptionsBuilder.Get());
```

the next line is required to inject the `DbContext` into a controller or a service (if I add `ServiceLifetime.Scoped` as a second parameter to the method above - `AddDbContext` - the feature doesn't work):

```
services.AddScoped(p => new AppDbContext(AppDbContextOptionsBuilder.Get(), p.GetService<ITenantProvider>()));
```

(`Entity Framework` is a separate project in my solution)

---

When using `.AddScoped` method - we can pass `TenantProvider` into constructor by resolving it using `.GetService` method.

Does anyone have an idea of how to resolve `TenantProvider` in `.AddDbContext` method?

Additional info:

I was trying to replace `ITenantProvider` in the constructor of `DbContext` with `IHttpContextAccessor` - the latter is registered as singleton. But the `acessor` parameter is still `null`.

`services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t really understand what your `AddScoped` call is supposed to do. `AddDbContext` will already register the database context properly with the service collection. So when you resolve the context through dependency injection, additional dependencies will be automatically resolved.

So it should be enough to do this:

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => …);

services.AddSingleton<ITenantProvider, TenantProvider>();
```

And then, you can depend on your `AppDbContext` using constructor injection, e.g. in your controllers.

---

Two notes though:

1. When configuring options, you should *modify* the passed options object. So you should not just return `AppDbContextOptionsBuilder.Get()` but instead use the passed options object and edit that.
2. You should really think about whether your database context having a dependency on your tenant provider is the right thing to do. As per [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), your database should only do a single thing and that is provide database access.

   Depending on how your tenant provider affects your database access, it might make more sense to move this dependency up one level into some service that uses both the database context and the tenant provider to query data in the right way.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer! 
A couple of things - `.AddDbContext` method accepts action, so I can't pass options object directly to it.
Another thing is `.AddSingleton` - `provider` is still `null` for some reason.
Thanks for mentioning SRP. I wonder if I should use Repository pattern here (something like `generic repository`)? 
I'm supposed to filter data by `TenantID` and `IsDeleted` fields for now - I wonder what's the best way to go about it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50877329/5374333 the guys recommend to stay away from repositories when dealing with DbContext

Comment: regarding `services.AddScoped(p => new AppDbContext(AppDbContextOptionsBuilder.Get()));` -  I've amended my question - made a mistake, sorry - in fact this is required to get `DbContext` working in a controller or a service by injecting it.

Comment: As I said, you should _not_ pass an options object, but instead edit the object you get in the action. You are currently replacing the options object with your own object that you get from `AppDbContextOptionsBuilder.Get()`. That’s what you should not do. – And no, having a separate `AddScoped` call that registers the database context is **not** required and will most likely cause you problems. And no, don’t use a repository here but some higher-level service instead.

Comment: I tend to agree the approach you've suggested is a lot better. But if I follow it - I'll end up having a filter expression in almost every service method. So, filtering data manually seems to be a laborious task, unless I missed something.