# confusion about generic repository and dbContext

Tags: model-view-controller, repository-pattern

im new in MVC,i have a project used repository and unit of work,in the repository of the project its written :

```
private DbContext context;
    private DbSet<TEntity> dbQueryable;

    public GenericEFRepository(DbContext context) : base(context.Set<TEntity>())
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbQueryable = (DbSet<TEntity>)this.Queryable;
    }
```

can anyone explain what does it do and tell me what :base is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well from the code it looks that you are using Entity Framework. First two lines are just objects of EF. The `GenericEFRepository` is generic method which must be the part of Generic Repository I guess.

With `: base(context.Set<TEntity>()` code, you are calling constructor of your base class. Look at the definition of `GenericEFRepository` class where you have specified the base class.

Finally, the method body returns `IQueryable` which you can consume in your calling code.

---

But, this all needs to be improved. Generic repository is considered an anti pattern. I suggest you understand the repository pattern before you implement it. Returning `IQueryable` breaks the basic purpose of repository.

Please refer following answers for more information:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49974458/5779732
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49850950/5779732