# Cannot pass object to Dapper.SimpleCrud insert

Tags: c#, dapper, dapper-simplecrud

I am using Dapper with the Dapper.SimpleCrud extension.

In my Dapper class, I have made an abstraction of the insert method, like this:

```
public static int Insert(object entity) {
    try {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            return sqlConnection.Insert(entity) ?? -1;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        // log
        return -1;
    }
}
```

This lets me call insert and pass an object of any type that is in the db.
The code that currently calls this method looks like this:

```
DapperORM.Insert(new Menu {
                    RestaurantID = RestaurantID,
                    Name = Name});
```

This throws an error: `{"Incorrect syntax near ')'."}`
Ok, so now I think there is something wierd with the data I pass in or something. But no. **When I change my own Insert method to take a `Menu`-object instead of a general `object`, it works.** 
The Dapper.SimpleCrud Insert overload method obviously can't figure out which object it is. Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at the generated SQL? In stack trace may be? I guess it must be missing name of database table. Yes; *I guess*. Because I never used SimpleCRUD.

> an object of any type that is in the db

How do SimpleCRUD know that the `object` you send in is "of type **that is in the db**"?

I think `object` type parameter is the problem. To accept "an object of any type **that is in the db**" you should consider converting your method to use generic type instead of `object`.

> When I change my own Insert method to take a Menu-object instead of a general object, it works.

This confirms my earlier diagnosis.

Convert your method to *something* like below:

```
public static int Insert<TPoco>(TPoco entity) where TPoco : class
```

or

```
public static int Insert<TPoco>(TPoco entity) where TPoco : BasePoco
```

or similar as per your other code structure.

Comment: You may refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45460483/5779732) example code. In that code, entire class is generic; in your case, only one method is generic. Also, that code uses different toolkit; still the concept is similar. Hope this helps you.