# Have a base entity class with CRUD implementation and a primary key ID that can be changed by the classes implementing it

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dapper, clean-architecture

In order to not rewrite basic CRUD for each entity I want to implement a base entity class with the base CRUD operations that can be implemented by any other entity.

The **problem** is I'm using Dapper for mapping with Dapper.Contrib and my database tables primary keys are never named Id - I can't use the Dapper mapper then.

I can't figure out a way to have a base class for a simple CRUD for each entity.

Comment: Instead of putting those methods in POCO, if you agree for Repository, have a look at `BaseRepository` class and `SetDbId` method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45460483/5779732). That is implemented with Dapper Extensions and you are using Contrib; but that should not change much.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very nice implementation without contrib of the generic repository pattern here: https://itnext.io/generic-repository-pattern-using-dapper-bd48d9cd7ead

Effectively you create the insert like this:

```
 public async Task InsertAsync(T t)
        {
            var insertQuery = GenerateInsertQuery();

            using (var connection = CreateConnection())
            {
                await connection.ExecuteAsync(insertQuery, t);
            }
        }

private string GenerateInsertQuery()
        {
            var insertQuery = new StringBuilder($"INSERT INTO {_tableName} ");

            insertQuery.Append("(");

            var properties = GenerateListOfProperties(GetProperties);
            properties.ForEach(prop => { insertQuery.Append($"[{prop}],"); });

            insertQuery
                .Remove(insertQuery.Length - 1, 1)
                .Append(") VALUES (");

            properties.ForEach(prop => { insertQuery.Append($"@{prop},"); });

            insertQuery
                .Remove(insertQuery.Length - 1, 1)
                .Append(")");

            return insertQuery.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Woah, okay - this is another way to solve my problem that I couldn't find a solution to before which brought me to dapper.contrib to avoid writing a lot of SQL. Thank you, I will consider this approach as well.

Comment: Indeed, while contrib really helps, this could also work too!

Answer (score 1):

Even though [@Athanasios Kataras](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60150007/3624069) answer works I still went with using the Dapper.contrib extension because it's more clear in my opinion.

I went the route of using Dapper.contrib and creating a Base Repository class which then was used by every other repository. 
Primary Keys (IDs) were handled by using data annotations that Dapper provides on the entities ([Key], [ExplicitKey]).

**Example of some repository class implementing the Base Repository:**

```
public class ACRepository : BaseRepository<ACEntity>, IACRepository
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _dbConnection;

    public ACRepository(IDbConnection _dbconn) : base(_dbconn)
    {
        _dbConnection = _dbconn;
    }

    // Some other methods that require more complicated queries
}
```

**Base Repository class:**

```
using Dapper.Contrib.Extensions;

public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _dbConnection;

    public BaseRepository(IDbConnection _dbconn)
    {
        _dbConnection = _dbconn;
    }

    public async Task Add(T entity)
    {
        var result = await _dbConnection.InsertAsync(entity);
    }

    public async Task<bool> Delete(T entity)
    {
        return await _dbConnection.DeleteAsync(entity);
    }

    public async Task<bool> Update(T entity)
    {
        return await _dbConnection.UpdateAsync(entity);
    }

    public async Task<T> GetById(object id)
    {
        return await _dbConnection.GetAsync<T>(id);
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll()
    {
        return await _dbConnection.GetAllAsync<T>();
    }
}
```

**An Entity:**

```
using Dapper.Contrib.Extensions;

[Table("table_name")]
public class SquawkRegisterPMEEntity
{
    [ExplicitKey]
    public string SomeKey { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int SomeOtherKey{ get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty1 { get; set; }
}
```

*[Key]* is used if the value is generated by the database.

*[ExplicitKey]* is used when the Id is specified manually.