# Is AsList() better than ToList() with IDbConnection.Query() which returns IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, dapper, database-performance

I read this answer from Marc Gravell (@MarcGravell): https://stackoverflow.com/a/47790712/5779732

The last line says:

> As a minor optimization to your code: prefer AsList() to ToList() to avoid creating a copy.

That statement is about `QueryMultiple()` which returns `GridReader`.

In my understanding, `System.Linq` provides an extension method `IEnumerable.ToList()`. Following is from [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) about `ToList()`.

> The ToList(IEnumerable) method forces immediate query evaluation and returns a List that contains the query results. You can append this method to your query in order to obtain a cached copy of the query results.

`IDbConnection.Query()` will ALWAYS return `IEnumerable` or `null`. Null-check could be easily done in calling code. What difference does `AsList` makes then?

If my understanding is correct, `AsList` will always internally call `ToList` which will create a copy.

Considering this, is `AsList()` better than `ToList()` with `IDbConnection.Query()` which returns `IEnumerable`? If yes; why?

What is that `AsList()` does internally that makes it a better choice in this case?

Comment: Look at [the source](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs) and you will see comments that indicate that if the data is already in a `List` data structure, then that list (i.e. instance) will be returned, rather than creating a new (i.e. copy) `List`.

Comment: @KennethK.: Agreed. But `IDbConnection.Query()` will ALWAYS return `IEnumerable` or `null`. Null check could be easily done in calling code. What difference does `AsList` makes then?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`AsList` is a custom Dapper extension method. All it does is checks if `IEnumerable<T>` you pass to it is really `List<T>`. If it is - it returns it back, just casts to `List<T>`. If it's not - it calls regular `ToList`. The point is - `ToList()` always creates a copy, even if what you pass to it is already a list. `AsList()` method avoids doing this copy, and so is useful if such copy is unnecessary.

In this specific scenario, you have the following code:

```
multipleresult.Read<MerchantProduct>()
```

where `multipleresult` is `GridReader`. `Read` has `buffered` argument which is true by default. When its true - `Read` will really return `List<T>`, so by calling `ToList` you will copy that list again without much reason.

The same is true for `IDbConnection.Query()` - is also has `buffered` parameter, which is true by default, so it will also by default return `List<T>`.

If you prefer to use `ToList()` - you can pass `buffered: false` to `Query()` or `Read()` to avoid creating that additional copy.

Comment: The extension can hurt imo. If someone changes the internal implementation, for example from list to array, the `AsList` suddenly returns a new list instead of returning the same instance. That might break code silently.

Comment: @TimSchmelter that's theoretically valid point, though I don't see how it can break code in this case (for dapper queries). You don't really care if it will return the same list or "new" one in this case - they are both "new" for you.

Comment: @TimSchmelter if I change the internal implementation of Dapper, I'll be sure to do something like annotate `AsList()` with `[Obsolete("...", false)]` with a message explaining what and why; I doubt it will change, however

Comment: @MarcGravell and why introduce that buffered parameter at all, and even set by default? To prevent accidental multiple executions of query by users unaware of how IEnumerable works?

Comment: @Evk partly that, although actually a more common scenario would be reading it once but *deferring* it - at which point the connection could be closed or another reader could be active; also partly to provide a unified API when you *really do* want raw streaming access (`buffered: false`)

Answer (score 6):

This extension is a custom dapper extension which does an additional check before calling `ToList`.  [Source](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs):

```
public static List<T> AsList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) 
    => (source == null || source is List<T>) ? (List<T>)source : source.ToList();
```

- `ToList` always creates a new `List<T>` instance and fills it with the given items
- `AsList` checks if the sequence is already a  `List<T>`, then it will just cast it

Of course this approach can be more efficient because casting something is much less work than creating and filling something new. So it's completely different.

This is kind of opinion based, but **i find this dangerous**. Someone might overlook the `AsList` and reads `ToList` or just don't know the difference. It's dangerous if someone changes the code later.

So for example  a method that takes `IEnumerable<T>` which uses `AsList`:

```
public static List<T> GetResult<T>(IEnumerable<T> seq)
{
    if(some condition here)
    {
        seq = seq.Where(some predicate here);
    }
    return seq.AsList()
}
```

Now code called this method with a list:

```
IEnumerable<string> sequence = (gets a list from somewhere)
List<string> userList = GetResult(sequence);
```

Later someone decides that  an array is more appropriate here:

```
IEnumerable<string> sequence = (gets an array from somewhere)
List<string> userList = GetResult(sequence);
```

This doesn't really hurt until now. Now a new List is initialized and filled because the source is not a list and can't be casted. So it's just less efficient. But if the logic also relied on the list being the same reference, this won't work anymore.

```
if(userList == seq)
{
    // do something
}
```

This is always `false` once the array is used . So the code was broken silently.

To cut a long story short: i don't like the `AsList` method. You can always check the type yourself.

Comment: The key point here is that `AsList()` is intended for use *with Dapper* to avoid a minor alloc; it is not intended for all purposes, although frankly it works fine in many of them

Comment: @MarcGravell: Well, you can use this extension also outside if you add `using Dapper;`, it's a public extension method of `IEnumerable<T>`. I tried to answer dapper independently. People might find it very useful so they adopt it in their own extension library. I just wanted to mention the drawback