# WebAPI - Repository class with DbContext object creation

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, repository-pattern

I am new to the ASP.NET WebAPI project and building the new project with the following structure :-

```
Project.MainAPIService
Project.BusinessManager
Project.Model
Project.Repository
Project.Common
```

I am using Autofac to perform the DI in the whole project. And the flow is like this :-

```
API controller   >>>>>> (DI) Business Manager >>>> (DI) Repository & creates the DBContext object manually.
```

My Repository class is looking like this. And now i want to pass the client-name dynamically into the Repository class, so that it makes the DB connection to the particular client db only. But i unable to pass the client-name from businessManager project to PDLRepository and further down to DBContext class.

```
public class MyRepository : IMyRepository, IDisposable
    {
        myContext _context = new myContext("ClientX");

        private IGenericRepository<Mapping> _docMappingGenericRepo;
        private IGenericRepository<Document> _DocGenericRepo;
        private IGenericRepository<Activity> _activityGenericRepo;
    }
```

mycontext class looks like this :-

```
 public partial class mycontext : DbContext
    {
        public mycontext (string ClientName)
            : base(ConnectionUtil.GetConnectionString(ClientName))
        { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<myContext>(null);
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<DocumentMapping> DocumentMapping { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<Document> Document { get; set; }
   }
```

Please suggest your views how to fix the myContext or MyRepository class accordingly. How will i pass the client-name from BusinessManager to Repository to DBContext class ?

Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not create `myContext` in Repository. Remove following line from Repository.

```
myContext _context = new myContext("ClientX");
```

Instead, create and manage `myContext` in `BusinessManager`. As `BusinessManager` already know `ClientName`, it can be created there without trouble with the same line we removed from Repository.

Now, inject `myContext` in Repository.

You apparently have multiple databases; one per client. So one database represent one client. Connection represents Database and `myContext` is handling Connection. So, approach I mentioned above makes more sense.

Repository executes the action, it should not control Connection. Using this approach, you can also include multiple Repositories in one `myContext` which will help you cover all those repositories under one transaction/UoW.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45029588/5779732) answer explains how to do this with Dapper. Technology may not be related to you; but rest of the details may help you.