# How to implement Unit Of Work pattern with Dapper in the multi thread environment?

Tags: c#, transactions, dapper

I am using the below Unit of work implementation in my application. 
URL reference :[How to implement Unit Of Work pattern with Dapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31298235/how-to-implement-unit-of-work-pattern-with-dapper)

This is working fine with single thread application. But if i want to use same code for  multi thread application, then its creating a problem.

**Example:** 
I am creating unit of work object with AddScoped 
`services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();`

Old Transaction object will be replaced by new transaction object, when more than one thread calling unit of work Begin() method in single web request.

Comment: What is the error your seeing? Can you post the stack trace for example? Or maybe some of the source code

Comment: Are you still working on that? I've created a simple unit of work implementation on top of Dapper, with some basic CQS in mind. https://github.com/giangcoi48k/Dapper.CQS. Please take a look and see if it can apply to your project.

Answer (score 0):

AddScoped create one instance per request, so, if you need execute many threads in a single request where each thread run into a transaction,using this unitofwork code,  I think you'll need to update your unitofwork code to manage one connection per thread