# How to use transaction across multiple method calls with Dapper?

Tags: transactions, dapper

I need to wrap some calls to methods that are doing `async` updates and inserts into my database.  All of the methods use this pattern for running the code:

```
 using (IDbConnection conn = Connection)
            {
                conn.Open();
                //TODO:  Table item quantity for the QTYALLOC field
                var sql = //sql statement;
                int x = await conn.ExecuteAsync(sql);
                return x > 0;
            }
```

Right now all of the methods return a `boolean`.  I want to wrap the calls in a transaction and either commit or rollback

```
                    await [InsertRecord];
                    //add the audit record
                    var addAudit = await [Insert Audit Record];
                    var updateOrd = await [Update Record]
                    var changePickStatus = await [Update Record]
                    if (locs.First().QTYTOTAL - ord.QTYPICKED <= 0)
                    {
                        await [Delete Record]; //delete the record

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //decrement the quantity for the location and update.
                        locs.First().QTYTOTAL -= ord.QTYPICKED;
                        await [Update Record]

                    }
```

I put the calls to the methods in the square [] brackets.  Right now each call returns a `boolean` to indicate it was successful or failed, I would like to wrap all these calls in one transaction to commit or rollback based on the outcome of each call.  I don't want to put all the SQL statements into one large call if I can help it, they are long and complex.  Can I pass in a transaction to each method call and apply it to each `ExecuteAsync` operation?  If so what would I pass back from the method to indicate success or failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the connection/transaction in each method call as parameter.

Following is a sort of *pseudo code* (syntax may not be accurate):

```
using (IDbConnection conn = Connection)
{
    using(var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())//Begin here
    {
        var addAudit = await [YourMethod(conn)];//Inject as parameter
        if(addAudit == false)
            transaction.Rollback();//Rollback if method call failed
        ...
        ...
        //Repeat same pattern for all method calls
        ...
        transaction.Commit();//Commit when all methods returned success
    }
}
```

The better solution is to use [Unit Of Work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45029588/5779732). But, this is only worth if you are implementing it on much broader level.

Comment: I used one connection and then opened it, added the transaction to the open connection and passed the connection and transaction into each method.  It appears to be working, but more testing will be required to ensure its success.  Thanks.