# Database locked error when using Begintransaction, multiple repositories, SQLite, UnitOfWork and Dapper

Tags: c#, sqlite, transactions, dapper

I'm trying to implement transactions with SQLite and Dapper but I'm getting "database is locked" error.

I'm using the UnitOfWork pattern suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45029588/583037).

This is the code:

**Controller.cs:**

```
public async Task MyMethodAsync()
{
    //**injecting unitOfWork but this is the implementation**
    var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source=TestDb;Mode=Memory;Cache=Shared"));

    using (var connection = unitOfWork.Connection)
    {
        connection.Open();
        
        unitOfWork.Begin();

        var myFirstRepository = new MyFirstRepository(unitOfWork);
        var mySecondRepository = new MySecondRepository(unitOfWork);

        try 
        {
            myFirstRepository.CreateStuff(); //Here it throws the exception "database is locked"
    
            mySecondRepository.CreateOtherStuff();
   
            unitOfWork.Commit();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
            unitOfWork.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

**MyFirstRepository.cs:**

```
public class MyFirstRepository
{
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;    

    public MyFirstRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) 
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public void CreateStuff()
    {
        using (var connection = _unitOfWork.Connection)
            {
                connection.Open();
                await connection.ExecuteAsync("INSERT INTO ...", param).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
    }
}
```

**MySecondRepository.cs:**

Similar implementation like MyFirstRepository.cs.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're opening the connection twice - once in `MyMethodAsync` and again in `MyFirstRepository.CreateStuff`. I don't see anything in the [documentation for the SQLiteConnection class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqliteconnection.open?view=msdata-sqlite-6.0.0) about what happens if you try to open a connection twice, but maybe that's causing the issue for you? I also noticed that in the post you linked about UnitOfWork that `connection.Open()` is only called once as well.