# Unit testing with microsoft access database in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a project and I used ms access as my database in my c# code. How will I do the unit tests for that part of the code?

Comment: By creating a connection to the database and running the queries? Its unclear what you are asking, why do you have concerns about unit testing with MS Access?

Comment: I recommend you to read this SO-post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000908/ways-of-unit-testing-data-access-layer