# JUnit 5: How to assert an exception is thrown in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, junit, junit5

version:

jdk1.8.0
Scala: 2.11

```
<properties>
 <junit.jupiter.version>5.2.0</junit.jupiter.version>
  <junit.platform.version>1.2.0</junit.platform.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.5</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
  <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
  <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I am following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40268446/1610034), which shows how to assert exception using junit 5 in java.

When I am trying to do the same in scala:

```
val closureContainingCodeToTest = () -> myClass.myMethod(data)   // or     val closureContainingCodeToTest = () => myClass.myMethod(data)
assertThrows(classOf[MyException], closureContainingCodeToTest)
```

I get this error:

```
 Error:(89, 48) type mismatch;
 found   : () => Unit
 required: org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable
    assertThrows(classOf[MyException], closureContainingCodeToTest)
```

This might be very simple question, but I could not found how to create Scala closure to Java `Executable` object in Scala.

### Edit:

Adding a simple complete test:

```
package com.my.lib

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable

class myTest {

  @Test
  def myTest = {
    val closureContainingCodeToTest:Executable = () => throw new RuntimeException()
    assertThrows(classOf[RuntimeException], closureContainingCodeToTest)
  }
}
```

I get following error:

```
Error:(11, 53) type mismatch;
 found   : () => Nothing
 required: org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable
    val closureContainingCodeToTest:Executable = () => throw new RuntimeException()
```

Comment: Your code compiles and runs for me - after I added `Unit` return type to `myTest` that is. If you are using IDE then I think this is just a need to clean/rebuild the project to take into account you added `Executable`. I can recreate your error if I remove `Executable` from `closureContainingCodeToTest` but it compiles after adding back in and cleaning/rebuilding.

Comment: @Nio This is strange, Even with `mvn clean compile test` from terminal, I get same error.

Answer (score 2):

If we want to do it in **Junit 5** style - you can do like in code below:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.{DisplayName, Test}
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.junit.{JUnitRunner, JUnitSuite}

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class Junit_5_Test extends JUnitSuite{

  object ExceptionTest {
    @throws(classOf[RuntimeException])
    def throwRunEx = throw new RuntimeException
  }

  @Test
  @DisplayName("Example with JUnitSuite")
  def throwsExceptionWhenCalled_With_JUnitSuite() {
    import ExceptionTest._
    assertThrows[RuntimeException]{ throwRunEx}
  }

}
```

To do like this - u need to include this in your `build.sbt`:

```
"org.junit.jupiter" % "junit-jupiter-api" % "5.2.0" % Test,
 "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.0-SNAP10" % Test
```

Answer (score 1):

You can coerce the function type `() => myClass.myMethod(data)` into an `Executable` by being explicit about the return type of the closure ie. add `Executable`

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable

class MyClassTests {

  val closureContainingCodeToTest: Executable = () => (new MyClass).myMethod(data)

  @Test
  def throwsExceptionWhenCalled(): Unit = {
    assertThrows(classOf[MyException], closureContainingCodeToTest)
  }

}
```

Alternatively, if you inline it then you don't even need to be explicit.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class MyClassTests {

  @Test
  def throwsExceptionWhenCalled(): Unit = {
    assertThrows(classOf[MyException], () => (new MyClass).myMethod(data))
  }

}
```

Also note that your test methods need to return `Unit` else they will never be run.

Comment: Thanks, however these I had tried and gives same error. Also I have `_execute` method, dont get confused this with `execute` method of `Executable` interface.

Comment: No worries. Thats weird, its compiling/running ok for me. Maybe post your full code? Are you using junit.jupiter 5.2.0?

Comment: Yes, junit.jupiter 5.2.0 I have updated the question with a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

To build off of the previous answers, I wanted to write multiple lines of test code and not call only MyClass.myMethod(data)

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable

class MyClassTest {

  @Test
  def throwsExceptionWhenCalled(): Unit = {
    assertThrows(classOf[MyException], new Executable {
      override def execute(): Unit = {
        val data = generateBadData()
        new MyClass().myMethod(data) // throws MyException
      }
    })
  }

}
```