# How can I ensure that a particular exception is thrown in JUnit5?

Tags: java, testing, junit5

With JUnit4 you could e.g. just write:

```
@Test (expectedException = new UnsupportedOperationException()){...}
```

How is this possible in JUnit5? I tried this way, but I'm not sure if this is equal.

```
@Test
    public void testExpectedException() {
        Assertions.assertThrows(UnsupportedOperationException.class, () -> {
            Integer.parseInt("One");});
```

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: No I can't try it, because I only have JUnit5 for my project

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those are equivalent.

```
public class DontCallAddClass {
    public void add() {
        throws UnsupportedOperationException("You are not supposed to call me!");
    }
}

public class DontCallAddClassTest {

    private DontCallAddClass dontCallAdd = new DontCallAddClass();

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void add_throwsException() {
       exception.expect(UnsupportedOperationException.class);
       dontCallAdd.add();
    }

    @Test(expected = UnsupportedOperationException.class)
    public void add_throwsException_differentWay() {
        dontCallAdd.add();
    }

    @Test
    public void add_throwsException() {
        Assertions.assertThrows(UnsupportedOperationException.class, dontCallAdd.add());
    }
}
```

The three test methods above are quivalent. In Junit 5 use the last one. It's the newer approach. It also allows you to take advantage of Java 8 lambdas. You can also checks for what the error message should be. See below:

```
public class DontCallAddClass {
    public void add() {
        throws UnsupportedOperationException("You are not supposed to call me!");
    }
}

public class DontCallAddClassTest {

    private DontCallAddClass dontCallAdd = new DontCallAddClass();

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void add_throwsException() {
       exception.expect(UnsupportedOperationException.class);
       exception.expectMessage("You are not supposed to call me!");
       dontCallAdd.add();
    }

    // this one doesn't check for error message :(
    @Test(expected = UnsupportedOperationException.class)
    public void add_throwsException_differentWay() {
        dontCallAdd.add();
    }

    @Test
    public void add_throwsException() {
        Assertions.assertThrows(UnsupportedOperationException.class, dontCallAdd.add(), "You are not supposed to call me!");
    }
}
```

check there for more information: [JUnit 5: How to assert an exception is thrown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268446/junit-5-how-to-assert-an-exception-is-thrown)

Hope this clear it up