# How to handle exceptions in Junit 5

Tags: java, junit, exception, junit5

I wrote a following test case. ImprovedAlternateIterator is a custom iterator that can accept multiple iterator in its constructor. I wrote a test case to  check its hasNext function. I am sure that it will throw an error but I don't know how to handle it. In junit4 we can use `@Test(expected = exception.class)` and its not possible in junit5.

I followed the documents and wrote the following test case with junit5 but it failed.

```
@Test
    public void hasNextTestWithEmptyConstructor() 
    ImprovedAlternateIterator <E> alternatingIterator = new ImprovedAlternateIterator<E>();
    assertThrows(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.class, () ->
    alternatingIterator.hasNext()); 
}
```

How can I handle the exception?

Comment: How exactly does it fail? What is the error/exception message you get? What do you expect instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JUnit 5: How to assert an exception is thrown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268446/junit-5-how-to-assert-an-exception-is-thrown)

Comment: @Progman it failed the test. no error message shown. I just want to handle the arrayindexoutofbound error