# How can I test my private constructors that throws an exception

Tags: java, testing, junit, constructor, private

I would like to know how can I test my private constructors that throws an IllegalStateException, I have search and found something like this:

```
@Test
public void privateConstructorTest()throws Exception{
    Constructor<DetailRecord> constructor = DetailRecord.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
    assertTrue(Modifier.isPrivate(constructor.getModifiers()));
    constructor.setAccessible(true);
    constructor.newInstance();
}
```

and this is the constructor:

```
private DetailRecord(){
    throw new IllegalStateException(ExceptionCodes.FACTORY_CLASS.getMessage());
}
```

the test works if the constructors doesnt throw an exception

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156503/how-do-you-assert-that-a-certain-exception-is-thrown-in-junit-4-tests?rq=1 (Junit 4) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268446/junit-5-how-to-assert-an-exception-is-thrown (JUnit 5).

Answer (score 0):

Add the optional expected attribute to the **@Test** annotation. By following way test that passes when the expected ***IllegalStateException*** is raised:

```
@Test(expected=IllegalStateException.class)
public void privateConstructorTest() {
    Constructor<DetailRecord> constructor = DetailRecord.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
    assertTrue(Modifier.isPrivate(constructor.getModifiers()));
    constructor.setAccessible(true);
    constructor.newInstance();
}
```

Or you can catch the exception and validate it by following way:

```
@Test
public void privateConstructorTest() {
    Constructor<DetailRecord> constructor = DetailRecord.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
    assertTrue(Modifier.isPrivate(constructor.getModifiers()));
    constructor.setAccessible(true);
    Throwable currentException = null;
    try {
        constructor.newInstance();
    catch (IllegalStateException exception) {
        currentException = exception;
    }
    assertTrue(currentException instanceof IllegalStateException);
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work, I got this when I execute the test, ava.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException, Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException

Comment: The cause of the `InvocationTargetException` **is** the exception thrown by the private constructor

Comment: Okay then change to InvocationTargetException the exception and the error message in order to compare it