# How to test exception scenario in junit 5 in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I have a void method that does some tasks trying to test exception scenarios but the test case is getting failed.

```
public void completetask(){
   try{
     RemoteUser rm = usrRepo.findById(12);
     assistenRepo.save(rm);
   }catch(Exception e){
    log.error("Exception occurred while making changes {}", e,getMessage());
   }
}
```

How can we test the exception scenario here on JUnit 5?

I have tried this but it's not working

```
@Test
public void completetaskTest(){
    RemoteUser rm = getDummyRemoteUsr();
    Mockito.when(usrRepo.findById(12)).thenReturn(rm);
    Mockito.when(assistenRepo.save(rm)).thenThrow(new Exception("Error Abnormal"));
    Exception exception = Assestions.assertThrow(Exception.class, () -> usrService.completetask());
    String expectedMessage = "Exception occurred while making changes";
    String actualMessage = exception.getMessage();
    Assertions.assetTrue(actualMessage.contains(expectedMessage));
}
```

I am getting an error for this test case - the check exception is invalid for this method
Invalid java.lang.Exception : Error

Can I know what wrong I am doing here ?

Comment: Can you share more details about the error? For example the stack trace could be helpful.

Comment: This the only error i am getting, Is there any other way to test this scenario

Comment: There is no exception thrown from the method `completeTask` as it is caught and only logged

Comment: did you try throwing new Exception inside catch statement and add method signature with throws Excepetion  or custom exception ?

Comment: The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40268447/10343888) helps you.

Comment: @Fati, I am also doing in same way

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting your method to thrown an exception but in your code, you're handling and logging the exception and no exception is thrown:

```
public void completetask(){
   try {
     RemoteUser rm = usrRepo.findById(12);
     assistenRepo.save(rm); // <-- Exception is thrown... 
   } catch(Exception e){ // <-- Catched here
    log.error("Exception occurred while making changes {}", e,getMessage());
   }
   // <-- Method finishes normally. 
}
```

You should be seeing the following in the output:

```
Exception occurred while making changes Error Abnormal
```

But your test will be failing here:

```
   Exception exception = Assestions.assertThrow(Exception.class, () -> usrService.completetask());
```

Because the exception was never thrown. If you comment out the exception handling `try / catch`  it will pass that point but now it will fail comparing the error messages.

EDIT:

> *I know this scenario but the problem here is how to solve this issue? How can we write test scenario for this condition –*

If you want to verify your exception was handled just remove verification:

```
@Test
public void completetaskTest(){
    RemoteUser rm = getDummyRemoteUsr();
    when(usrRepo.findById(12)).thenReturn(rm);
    when(assistenRepo.save(rm)).thenThrow(new Exception("Error Abnormal"));
    assertTrue(true); // if we reached this line, in means the error has handled. 

}
```

If you really want to go further and check if the message matches (which it might be overkill) you can check the logger, but again, I would't recommend it.

Something like this:

```
@Auto
Logger log;

...
@Test
public void completetaskTest(){
    RemoteUser rm = getDummyRemoteUsr();
    when(usrRepo.findById(12)).thenReturn(rm);
    when(assistenRepo.save(rm)).thenThrow(new Exception("Error Abnormal"));
   
    // Verify the `log.error` was invoked with exactly those parameters
    verify(log, times(1)).error("Exception occurred while making changes {}", "Error Abnormal");

}
```

That means the exception was thrown, cached and the logger was invoked.

Comment: I know this scenario but the problem here is how to solve this issue? How can we write test scenario for this condition

Comment: @NewDBLearner See the updated answer

Comment: ```org.mockitio.exceptions.base.MockitoException.    Checked Exception is invalid for this method. Invalid java.lang.exception: Error Abnormal``` No its not working

Comment: Figure out what kind of exceptions do the `save` method throws and then use that in the `thenThrow` call. It seems the problem is you're instrumenting the `when/thenThrow` with an exception that `save` cannot throw in the first place, hence the error. Then the rest of the answer above still applies.

Comment: Most likely `save` doesn't throw a checked exception (like `java.lang.Exception`) and it might fail somehow else. Try throwing a `RuntimeException` just to verify, but definitely you'll be better off if you handle something that can actually happen

Answer (score 1):

You are not throwing your error, you are just writing a log with one log line.

```
catch(Exception e){
   log.error("Exception occurred while making changes {}", e,getMessage());
}
```

Here is the javadoc on `Assertions.assertThrows`:

> Assert that execution of the supplied executable throws an exception of the expectedType and return the exception.
> If no exception is thrown, or if an exception of a different type is thrown, this method will fail.
> If you do not want to perform additional checks on the exception instance, ignore the return value.

That's why your `assertThrows` method will fail under all circumstances.

So either throw an error in your method you want to test, or check the log print in exceptions for testing.