# How to test an exception case for a method that doesn't throw the exception using JUnit & Mockito?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am trying to test the below function for exception case,

```java
public String someMethod() {
    String result = "default";

    try {
        result = a.something();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    return result;
}
```

I want to verify that "e.printStackTrace()" is being called. Here's what I tried,

```java
Exception e = spy(new Exception());
when(a.something()).thenThrow(e);
verify(e).printStackTrace();
```

but the verify statement fails. Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 2):

Your test is not calling `someMethod()`. You have the "given" part (the `spy` and `when` calls) and the "then" part (the `verify` call), but you're missing the "when" part - the actual code to test. As a result, the mocked `a.something()` method is not called and no exception is thrown.

To test this you need to create an instance of the class where `someMethod` is defined, then make sure it's `a` field is the mocked `a` field/variable (without more information I can't tell how to do that). Then you need to call `someMethod()` on that instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Assertions.assertThrows()` to test if the Exception is occuring or not duirng the method invocation.

`Exception e = assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> {myObject.methodName();}); assertNotNull(e.getStackTrace());`

Here is the reference - [JUnit 5: How to assert an exception is thrown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268446/junit-5-how-to-assert-an-exception-is-thrown)

Update: `assertThrows()` can be useful only if code is throwing an exception.

Comment: In this case, the code to test (not `a.something()` but `someMethod`) doesn't throw an exception but it handles it internally. That makes `assertThrows` unusable.

Answer (score 1):

In Mockito tests, you can verify whether a method was called or not, but verifying if a stack trace is printed directly is not straightforward.

However, you can redirect the standard output (`System.out`) to a different stream and then assert that the expected stack trace is printed to that stream.

```
public class YourTestClass {

    private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private final PrintStream originalOut = System.out;

    @Before
    public void setUpStreams() {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @After
    public void restoreStreams() {
        System.setOut(originalOut);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() {
        String result = objUnderTest.someMethod();

        // Verify that the exception printed to System.out
        assertTrue(outContent.toString().contains("Your StackTrace Exception"));
    }
}
```

Please note that manipulating `System.out` in tests might have some side effects, and it's generally a good practice to use a logging framework and then test against the logs rather than the standard output.

However, if you have to deal with `printStackTrace()`, this approach can be useful.